# Where should I create an instance of Service() if I can't place it on ViewModel?

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel

I create an foreground service named `ServiceRecord()` in Android Studio project, the service will return some state to notice UI when it running.

In ordr to interact with UI, I start the service with Bind method in ViewModel(), and the Compose UI will update automatically based the ViewModel().

Unfortunately, I get the following warning about `private var mService: ServiceRecord? = null` in `ViewModel()`.

*This field leaks a context object*

Where should I create an instance of Service() if I can't place it on `ViewModel` ?

```
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
): ViewModel()
{

    var elapsedTime by mutableStateOf("00:00.00")
            private set

    private val updateElapsedTime: UpdateElapsedTime = { elapsedTime = it}

    private var mService: ServiceRecord? = null   //It displays "This field leaks a context object"

    fun startRecord() {
        mService?.let{
            it.startRecord(updateElapsedTime)
        }
    }

    private val serviceConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        ...
    }

    fun bindService() {
        Intent(mApplication , RecordService::class.java).also { intent ->
            mApplication.bindService(intent, serviceConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
        }
    }

    fun unbindService() {
       ...
    }
   
}

class ServiceRecord: Service() {

    @Inject lateinit var recordSound: IRecordSound

    inner class MyBinder : Binder() {
        val serviceRecord: ServiceRecord
            get() = this@ServiceRecord
    }

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent): IBinder {
        return MyBinder()
    }

   fun startRecord(updateElapsedTime: UpdateElapsedTime){
       recordSound.startRecord(updateElapsedTime)
   }

}

interface IRecordSound { 
   fun startRecord(updateElapsedTime: UpdateElapsedTime, updateCurrentRecordIndex: UpdateCurrentRecordIndex)
}
```

**Added Content**

To CommonsWare: Thanks!

When I run the app and start recording, the user interface (UI) displays the elapsed time of the recording. If I need to record for a long time, I can switch to a game UI to play, and the app's notification icon will be displayed on the top toolbar of my Android mobile phone, allowing the recording to keep running in the background.

If I tap the app's notification icon, the UI of the app will be restored and the elapsed time of the recording will be displayed again. I can then click the "Stop" button to end the recording.

Therefore, I believe that using a foreground service is suitable for the app's requirements because I need the UI to display the elapsed time when recording, and the app can continue recording sound even when I am playing a game.

If I implement the function of recording sound in a separate thread, I am concerned that the system might kill the thread when I switch to a game UI to play. Is my understanding correct?

**Added Content Again**

The section below answerred by AI.

As the warning message indicates, holding a reference to Service in ViewModel can cause a memory leak. In order to avoid this issue, you can move the instance of Service to an application-level context or to an activity-level context.

One possible solution is to create an instance of Service in the Application class and keep a reference to it there. The Application class is a singleton that represents the entire application, so it provides a convenient place to store global state that needs to persist across different activities and components.

Here is an example of how you can create an instance of Service in the Application class:

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    private var mService: ServiceRecord? = null

    fun getService(): ServiceRecord? {
        return mService
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val intent = Intent(this, ServiceRecord::class.java)
        startService(intent)
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    private val mConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            mService = (service as ServiceRecord.MyBinder).serviceRecord
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
            mService = null
        }
    }
}
```

Then, in your ViewModel, you can retrieve the Service instance using the getSystemService() method:

```
class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val application: MyApplication
): ViewModel() {

    private var mService: ServiceRecord? = null

    fun bindService() {
        mService = application.getService()
    }

    fun unbindService() {
        ...
    }
}
```

**I modify some codes based AI answer, is that good solution?**

```
class MyApplication : Application() {

    private var mService: ServiceRecord? = null

    fun getService(): ServiceRecord? {
        return mService
    }

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()

        val intent = Intent(this, ServiceRecord::class.java)
        startService(intent)
        bindService(intent, mConnection, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE)
    }

    private val mConnection = object : ServiceConnection {
        override fun onServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, service: IBinder) {
            mService = (service as ServiceRecord.MyBinder).serviceRecord
        }

        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName) {
            mService = null
        }
    }
   
    fun startRecord(){
        mService?.let{
             it.startRecord()
        }
    }

}

class RecordSoundViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val application: MyApplication
): ViewModel() {

    fun startRecord(){
         application.startRecord()
     }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the service will return some state to notice UI when it running

If you have UI in the foreground, you do not need a service.

> Where should I create an instance of Service()

You should not be creating an instance of *any* `Service`. You use `startService()`, `startForegroundService()`, or *maybe* `bindSerivice()` with `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`, to have the OS create an instance of the `Service`.

To avoid the Lint warning about the leaked context, you would need to:

- Create an AIDL-defined interface
- Have your service implement that interface (via the `.Stub` that AIDL generates)
- Have your `onBind()` function return the interface, rather than the class
- Have your property in your viewmodel be typed as the interface, not the class

---

However, at some point, you are going to need to deal with the fact that none of this is likely to work the way that you want.

From the names in your code snippet, my guess is that you are trying to record audio in the background. That is going to require a foreground service, and you cannot set one of those up using `bindService()` and `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`. You need to use `startForegroundService()` to start the service, with the service then calling `startForeground()`. At most, you might sometime later use `bindService()` without `BIND_AUTO_CREATE`, but I don't know what the point would be. with your current code, at best, your recording will stop after one minute in the background, and it might stop sooner than that.

Bear in mind that a service is purely a marker, telling the OS that you are trying to do background work. IMHO, any actual business logic that resides *in* the service is misplaced, because testing a service is a serious pain.

If I had to record audio in the background, and I was willing to have the recording be in the same OS process as the UI, this is what I would do:

1. Have a separate Kotlin class that handles the single responsibility of recording audio
2. Have a separate singleton Kotlin object (via Koin or Dagger/Hilt) that handles the single responsibility of relaying updates from the object from point 1 to the rest of the app, via a reactive API (e.g., `StateFlow`)
3. Have a *tiny* foreground service that simply creates the instance of the object from point 1, so the recording can happen
4. Arrange to start that foreground service from... something (it is unclear what the trigger is for that)
5. For any activities/fragments/composables that need to know what is going on with the recording, inject the singleton from point 2 into the appropriate viewmodel, and have it observe whatever API the singleton is publishing

Comment: @HelloCW: "I believe that using a foreground service is suitable for the app's requirements because I need the UI to display the elapsed time when recording, and the app can continue recording sound even when I am playing a game." -- agreed. You just are not setting up a foreground service in your code in the question. "Is my understanding correct?" -- I did not discuss threads. I did discuss *processes*. In your case, my guess is that you are fine with a single process.

Comment: Thank you very much! Would you please to see my added content again in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW: First, Stack Overflow is not a discussion board -- editing questions to introduce follow-on questions is not how this site is supposed to work. Second, I am not here to help debug. debate, or defend generated code.